# Show that $0 \leq a < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}$ implies $a=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, suppose $0 \leq a < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}$, then $a=0$.
Is this statement correct? I tried to prove this by contradiction through convergence definition. But I think I am stuck.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. In your opinion, which number is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$?

Comment: Since $\lim\frac1n=0,$ this is just the statement that $0\leq a<0,$ and then $a$ does not exist.

Comment: I think it should be $0$? But the strictly less than sign is bothering me.

Comment: It is true if $a\geq 0$ and $a<\frac1n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N^{>0},$ then $a=0,$ but that is not what the question asks.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your implication is true since its hypothesis is never true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot even be true. You have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0,$$

and so the given inequality states that

$$0\leq a<0.$$

But clearly this cannot ever happen, as there is no number with this property. However if you instead had

$$0\leq a\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n},$$

then it reads

$$0\leq a\leq 0,$$

and so clearly $a=0$. Now I'm guessing the context where this have arisen might have come from something like having that

$$0\leq a<\frac{1}{n}$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and then letting $n\to\infty$. The thing you have to be careful with there is that **limits do not preserve strict inequalities**, and so any strict inequality becomes nonstrict when taking the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The original context indeed has something like $0 \leq a < \frac{1}{n}$. The original problem is given $E, F \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a convergent sequence $\{x_n\} \in F$ such that $\lim x_n = x \in F$ and $d(x_n, E) < \frac{1}{n}$, what the problem want me to show is $d(x, E) = 0$. I think your answer helps, I just need to think a bit more.

Comment: If it is $$0\leq a < lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ then you could use surreal numbers since the limit is $$\frac{1}{\aleph_0}>\frac{1}{\aleph_i},i\geq 1$$